# How to get the currently typed text from edittext using textwatcher?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

For example: if I typed "hello sir", then how can I get "hello" as soon as I tapped space bar before I start typing "sir" using `textwatcher` in android.
I need currently typed single text from `edittext` as soon as user hit the space bar not all the string from `edittext`. 
Can anyone provide reliable idea using `textwatcher`?

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charsequence, int i, int j, int k) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // I need only currently typed text not all the string from edittext
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the entire string whenver onTextChanged is called, there is no "when spacebar is pressed" callback, so you'll have to write your own.

An idea could be the following:
In onTextChanged(), check the string for any spaces, and if there is any found, go through the string, split the string into an array of space seperated strings.
Then you have each string in an array, and then simply find the one you need.

This would turn the string "How are you doing today?" into an array of "How" "are" "you" "doing" "today?", and then its a simple case of array indexing to find the string you need.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Remember to upvote / accept my answer if it helped you.